# Modified date is not updating after copying files

Tags: c#

I am importing a folder and all its content including subdirectories and files into my application data directory for my application to use.

I have tried many solutions but the one that worked is this.

```
//Create all of the directories
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories))
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

//Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories))
File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
```

This works great except for the fact that if the files are already present in the destination directory, their data is updated, but their modified date is not updated at all.

Comment: How are you checking the modified dates?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, can I please see a screenshot? Sure you can do a workaround of deleting first but there is a problem in that Windows File System doesn't reflect audit changes. I need to see the file/folder permissions too and the user you are running this code.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I find it hard to believe that the contents of the file would get updated without the timestamp being set.

Comment: is explorer caching it?

Comment: which value are you seeing? the old files or the copied ones?

Comment: Modified date is never updated when a file is copied, the file was not changed, just its location.

Comment: @Dan post that as the answer

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am simply showing column of modified date in windows explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified date is never updated when a file is copied, the file was not changed, just its location.